# Built-in Cycles Bevel Shader customization

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, bevel

There is a new feature now in master that can be used by downloading daily build of Blender:

https://builder.blender.org/download/

It's **bevel shader** for Cycles. I tested it and it works great. However, I have a few questions:

- How to exclude some edges from the influence of bevel shader?
- How to set different bevel radius per edge? Can bevel weight value be used somehow?
- How to exclude selected intersecting geometry from creating bevel?

[image]

Comment: If you need *that* level of customization you should probably be using manually bevel geometry in the first place. This also seems to be a development feature, not sure if many people here are aware of it yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use any attribute for the **bevel radius**.

I painted some vertex colors for example and connected them with the bevel radius input.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.

I found a workaround for some of my questions. The trick is to use different materials on different parts of the mesh, this way it's possible to have varying degrees of bevel. It's not an ideal solution though, because it does not solve the case when bevels are intersecting.

[image: Bevel shader]

2.

Another option is to use Render Bevel addon.

https://gumroad.com/l/render_bevel

https://twitter.com/JoseConseco3/status/938545842566369280